# How does vector calls copy constructor on specific location?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I was wondering how vector works in C++. When we add a new element and the vector runs out of the space, it allocates a new memory and copies all the previous elements to the new location.

Now, how this behavior is defined?

```
A* a = new A(prev_a);
```

will copy construct at new location allocated by new. But for vector, we have to allocate multiple objects. But we cannot do so because array new cannot have initialization arguments.

So I wonder, how does vector implement this? I assume that the vector allocate a memory first and calls a copy constructor at the specific location. How is this done? Thanks

Comment: You can check out the (GCC) implementation for the member _M_allocate_and_copy: `template<typename _ForwardIterator >
pointer std::vector::_M_allocate_and_copy ( size_type  __n,
_ForwardIterator  __first,
_ForwardIterator  __last 
)`

Comment: For reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct

Comment: Note that there is *one* allocation and *multiple* copy constructions, not an allocation plus copy construction *per element*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I assume that the vector allocate a memory first and calls a copy constructor at the specific location.

That is right, these are two separate steps:

1. Memory allocation using [`allocator::allocate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate).
2. Initialization. It copy/move-constructs the elements using [allocator::construct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct), which normally uses placement new.